# How to compute the level of inheritance for two types?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

Assume that I have the following classes and inheritance:

```
public class BaseClass{}
public class DClass:BaseClass {}
public class DClass2:DClass {}
public class DClass3:Dclass2 {}
```

I can check that `DClass*` is a derived class of `BaseClass` by using the

```
typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DClass))
```

command.

But is there a way to compute the levels of inheritance? Eg:

1. `BaseClass` is 0 level of inheritance from `BaseClass`
2. `DClass2` is 2 level of inheritance from `BaseClass`
3. `DClass3` is 1 level of inheritance from `DClass2`.

Comment: Use the [`BaseType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.basetype?view=net-5.0) property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by recursively going up the inheritance tree using `BaseType`:

```
public static int GetLevelOfInheritance(Type baseType, Type derivedType)
{
    if (baseType == derivedType)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (derivedType == typeof(object) || derivedType == null) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The two types are not related by inheritance!");
    }
    else
    {
        return 1 + GetLevelOfInheritance(baseType, derivedType.BaseType);
    }
}
```

However, being in an inheritance relationship is only a sufficient but not necessary condition that `IsAssignableFrom` returns true. It can also return true for interfaces that a class implements, or for the nullable version of a value type, or for bounded generic type parameters.

So before calling this method, you should check whether one type *inherits* from the other, rather is *assignable* from another, by using [`IsSubclassOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.issubclassof?view=net-5.0).